# Given $f(x)=3x+4$ and $g(x)=ax+b$ and that $\forall x \ f(g(x))=x$ how can I determine a and b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Maybe I am just tired, but I can't seem to figure out how to work a question like this out:

$f(x)=3x+4$

$g(x)=ax+b$

$\forall x, \ \ f(g(x))=x$

Find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Well, what is $f\circ g(x)$?

Comment: $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = x$ for all x.

Comment: Well, sure.  But you have $f,g$ explicitly so you can simply write down $f\circ g(x)$.  Then set that expression to $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$f(g(x))=3(ax+b)+4=x$$ solve this equation

Comment: This equation is true for all $x$. So it is true for $x=0$. This will give you $b$. It is also true for $x=1$. This will give you $a$

Comment: Oh, yeah. That makes complete sense. Thanks @BernardMassé and Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.

Answer (score 1):

a = 1/3  ,  b = -4/3

g(x) = 0 for x = -b/a 
So,  f(0) = -b/a 
    4a=-b
f(x) = 0 for x=-4/3 
So,  b = -4/3

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the $y$-intercept of $f$ is the zero of $g$, hence $g(x)=\text{slope}\cdot(x-4)$. Now the zero of $f$, namely $-4/3$, is the $y$-intercept of $g$, hence $g(x)=\frac13(x-4)$.